# Directly accessing struct inner value

Tags: c#, struct, nullable

Not sure how to word this or search for it as I lack the "real name" for this.

Certain structs in C# can be used directly as their containing type, take Nullable<> for instance, a Nullable can directly be treated as an int, for example:

```
Nullable<int> ex;

void Example(){
    ex += 1;
}
```

My question is now to implement this kind of behaviour in my own structs, for example I could make a Savable and still be able to treat the variable like a normal int like in nullable? instead of doing mySavable.value, for example.

Hope my question is clear enough, it's without a doubt a duplicate question, but I could not find another in my searches as I'm lacking the proper name of this "technique". So sorry in advance for that!

Thanks very much!

Comment: [Overload operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288467(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: Or implicit conversion.

Comment: `Nullable<>` should be directly supported by the compiler that does some tricks...

Comment: @xanatos, OP is asking about custom structures (*"my own structs"*), `Nullable<>` is just an example.

Comment: @Sinatr Sadly he chose a bad example, because `Nullable<>` is compiler-supported :-)

Comment: Have you tried looking @[ReferenceSource](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/nullable.cs,ffebe438fd9cbf0e)?

Comment: I had never stumbled across the ReferenceSource before, it looks extremely useful, thanks @m.rogalski

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Nullable<>` type is a bad example. It is compiler supported, and it does magic that no one else can do.

You can define some implicit/explicit cast operators, that will convert `YourStruct <-> int` implicitly or explicitly, or you can define some operators that accept for example `YourStruct + int`. Both solutions will solve your question. Note that to obtain the `+=` operator you only need to define the `+` operator that returns a `YourStruct` (or define an implicit conversion `int -> YourStruct`).

For example, overloading the `operator+(Example1, Example1)` and overloading the implicit cast conversion from/to `int` you could:

```
public struct Example1
{
    public readonly int Value;

    public Example1(int value)
    {
        this.Value = value;
    }

    public static Example1 operator +(Example1 t1, Example1 t2)
    {
        return new Example1(t1.Value + t2.Value);
    }

    // This is used only for the "int v1 = e1;" row
    public static implicit operator int(Example1 value)
    {
        return value.Value;
    }

    public static implicit operator Example1(int value)
    {
        return new Example1(value);
    }
}
```

and then

```
Example1 e1 = 1;
Example1 e2 = 2;
Example1 sum1 = e1 + e2;
Example1 sum2 = e1 + 4;
Example1 sum3 = 4 + e1;
sum3 += sum1;
sum3 += 1;
int v1 = e1;
```

Or you could simply overload the various `operator+` between `Example2` and `int`:

```
public struct Example2
{
    public readonly int Value;

    public Example2(int value)
    {
        this.Value = value;
    }

    public static Example2 operator +(Example2 t1, Example2 t2)
    {
        return new Example2(t1.Value + t2.Value);
    }

    public static Example2 operator +(Example2 t1, int t2)
    {
        return new Example2(t1.Value + t2);
    }

    public static Example2 operator +(int t1, Example2 t2)
    {
        return new Example2(t1 + t2.Value);
    }
}
```

and then

```
Example2 e1 = new Example2(1);
Example2 e2 = new Example2(2);
Example2 sum1 = e1 + e2;
Example2 sum2 = e1 + 4;
Example2 sum3 = 4 + e1;
sum3 += sum1;
sum3 += 1;
int v1 = e1.Value;
```

(note that the `operator+` isn't commutative, so I have to define both the `Example2 + int` and the `int + Example2`)

Comment: Wow what a response, thanks very much
I had wondered if Nullable<> was using some special "cheats" ;)
Your explanation taught me a fair few new things, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0(v=vs.110).aspx#Operators). You will notice Nullable<T> overloads Implicit conversion operator. That's why T can be implicitly converted to Nullable<T>. If you need other operators you will have to overload them in your class.

Comment: It is the opposite... `T` can be implicitly converted to `T?`. `T?` must be explicitly converted to `T` (because it can throw if `T? == null`)